# Show number of rows and columns when all rows are displayed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The option `display.max_rows` is by default set to 60.
This means when there's more than 60 rows present in the dataframe, upon using `print(df)` it will crop it to show only 60 and at the end will display the number of rows and column, such as: `[61 rows x 22 columns]`

However, if there's 60 or less rows it will not display the shape information at the bottom.

How does one force it to always show the shape information at the bottom (in all cases even if there's just 1 row 1 column) without changing how many rows it shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to change `'show_dimensions'` option. It's set to `'truncate'` by default, so it only displays when the output is truncated:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('show_dimensions', True)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, (4,4)))
print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
    0   1   2   3
0  88  66  37  41
1  74  21   5   4
2  74  43  86  52
3  65  20  58  65

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Huh I don't know how but even after seeing `show_dimensions` in the docs it didn't register in my head that it's what it is! Oh, this will save me so much from the agony of "oh no now I need to go to the code and print the shape explicitly!" ! Thanks!!!

Comment: I guess I was foolishly expecting that similarly to `max_rows` it would be some option that would accept a number of the min_rows as to when to show the shape. But no it's a True/False scenario hah!